# Selenium Grid With Page Object Model Page Factory

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

How would I initialize the browser if I want to test on multiple browsers using Page Object Model Page Factory?

Currently I have iniatialized the browsers in my Base Class like this.

```
// initialise driver/browser

 public void initDriver() throws MalformedURLException{
   if(CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("firefox")){
       cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
       cap.setBrowserName("firefox"); // chrome,iexplore
       cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
   }else if (CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("chrome")){
       cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); // no need path of chrome exe
       cap.setBrowserName("chrome");
       cap.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);
   }else if (CONFIG.getProperty("browser").equals("iexplore")){
       cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer(); // no need path of chrome exe
       cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
       cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
   }
   if(driver == null){
       driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"),cap);
   }
   String waitTime=CONFIG.getProperty("default_implicitWait");
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Long.parseLong(waitTime), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
```

This however only runs my test my test only on one of the browsers.

This is my testng.xml file

```
<suite name="Selenium Grid with webdriver" >
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="Codes.listener.TestsListenerAdapter" />
</listeners>
<test name="Login test">
    <classes>
        <class name="Codes.testCases.LoginTest" ></class>  
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: do you mean you want to run in parallel?

Comment: Yes, i would like to run parallel.

Comment: How are you picking up the browser name from config file? The reason is since you have a if block do you think it can run for all the browsers?

Comment: I should be able to i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your browser initialization seems ok but I am wondering , why `cap` is not initialized when `driver == null` You should improve your `testng.xml` in following way:

To Run the test methods parallely:

```
<suite name="Selenium Grid with webdriver" parallel="methods" thread-count="5" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Codes.listener.TestsListenerAdapter" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Login test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Codes.testCases.LoginTest" ></class>  
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Similarly you can define `parallel = "classes"` or `parallel = "tests"` to choose the parallel execution level.

Comment: I tried using your code for testng.xml but the test is still running on one of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As @Priyanshu mentioned, you need to change your testng.xml. I believe that you have updated your testng.xml but as per your above testng.xml file you have only one `<class>` in `<test>`, so in your cases `parallel="methods"` (I assume you wanna execute different test scripts in parallel and not different methods of same test script) or `parallel="classes"` will not work. Change it to `parallel="tests"` and then try running it like this :-

```
<suite name="Selenium Grid with webdriver" parallel="tests" thread-count="5" >
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Codes.listener.TestsListenerAdapter" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Login test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Codes.testCases.LoginTest" ></class>  
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Login test2">
        <classes>
            <class name="Codes.testCases.LoginTest2" ></class>  
        </classes>
    </test>

   <test name="Login test3"> 

   <!-- class etc.. etc.. -->

   </test>

</suite>
```